# Split Date Range and Manipulating Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, recursive-query

I'm working on machine schedule project right now. I have table which I create for recording machine status. In this table I record Start and Finish Status. And right now I want to create report by that table if I input date between some period. Here's the table and expected result I want.

Source Table:

```
 machineid |      starttime      |      endtime        |  status | 
-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
   M1      | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-04 17:00:00 | running |
   M1      | 2020-01-04 17:00:00 | 2020-01-04 18:00:00 | down    |
   M1      | 2020-01-04 18:00:00 | 2020-01-05 14:00:00 | idle    |
   M2      | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-05 09:00:00 | running |
   M2      | 2020-01-05 09:00:00 | 2020-01-05 18:00:00 | idle    |
```

Expected Result:

**Input Start Date Report : 2020-01-01 00:00:00** and
**Input End Date Report : 2020-01-05 23:59:59**

```
machineid |    date    | running | idle | down | total |
----------+------------+---------+------+------+-------+
   M1     | 2020-01-01 |    24   |   0  |   0  |   24  |
   M1     | 2020-01-02 |    24   |   0  |   0  |   24  |
   M1     | 2020-01-03 |    24   |   0  |   0  |   24  |
   M1     | 2020-01-04 |    17   |   6  |   1  |   24  |
   M1     | 2020-01-05 |     0   |  14  |   0  |   14  |
   M2     | 2020-01-01 |    24   |   0  |   0  |   24  |
   M2     | 2020-01-02 |    24   |   0  |   0  |   24  |
   M2     | 2020-01-03 |    24   |   0  |   0  |   24  |
   M2     | 2020-01-04 |    24   |   0  |   0  |   24  |
   M2     | 2020-01-05 |     9   |   9  |   0  |   18  |
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to pivot your data in order to transform rows into columns

Comment: If i understand you well, you want to count hours for specific status and date. Am i right?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(machineid varchar(3), starttime  datetime, endtime datetime,  [status] varchar(20)) 

INSERT INTO @tmp (machineid, starttime, endtime,  [status])
VALUES('M1' , '2020-01-01 00:00:00' , '2020-01-04 17:00:00' , 'running') ,
('M1' , '2020-01-04 17:00:00' , '2020-01-04 18:00:00' , 'down') ,
('M1' , '2020-01-04 18:00:00' , '2020-01-05 14:00:00' , 'idle') ,
('M2' , '2020-01-01 00:00:00' , '2020-01-05 09:00:00' , 'running') ,
('M2' , '2020-01-05 09:00:00' , '2020-01-05 18:00:00' , 'idle')

;WITH CTE AS
(
    --initial data
    SELECT machineid, starttime, endtime, [status]
    FROM @tmp 
    --recursive part
    UNION ALL
    SELECT machineid, DATEADD(HH, 1, starttime) starttime, endtime, [status]
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(HH, 1, starttime) < endtime 
)
SELECT machineid, [date], COALESCE([running], 0) [running], COALESCE([idle], 0) [idle], COALESCE([down], 0) [down], COALESCE([running], 0)  + COALESCE([idle], 0) + COALESCE([down], 0) total
FROM
    (
        SELECT machineid, CONVERT(date, starttime) [date], [status], COUNT(starttime) cnt
        FROM CTE
        WHERE CONVERT(date, starttime) BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-05'
        GROUP BY machineid, CONVERT(date, starttime), [status]
) DT
PIVOT(MAX(cnt) FOR [status] IN ([running], [idle], [down])) PT
ORDER BY machineid, [date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: sorry for late reply..
thanks @Maciej Los for your answer, it's help me a lot, but just in case when i input range outside between recorded table. can it's show 0 in total result?
Input Start Date Report : 2020-01-01 00:00:00 and Input End Date Report : 2020-01-05 23:59:59

`
   M2     | 2020-01-04 |    24   |   0  |   0  |   24  |
   M2     | 2020-01-05 |     9   |   9  |   0  |   18  |
   M2     | 2020-01-06 |     0   |   0  |   0  |    0  |
`

Comment: In that case, you'll need to write another query... Then you have to join result.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with a recursive CTE for expanding the data (as the simplest solution to code).  However, I think conditional aggregation is then much simpler than `pivot`:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT machineid, starttime, endtime, status
      FROM t
      UNION ALL
      SELECT machineid, DATEADD(hour, 1, starttime) as starttime, endtime, [status]
      FROM CTE
      WHERE DATEADD(hour, 1, starttime) < endtime 
     )
SELECT machineid, CONVERT(date, starttime) as dte,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'running' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as running,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'idle' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as idle,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'down' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as down,
       COUNT(*) as total
FROM cte
WHERE starttime >= '2020-01-01' AND 
      starttime < '2020-01-06'
GROUP BY machineid, CONVERT(date, starttime)
ORDER BY machineid, CONVERT(date, starttime)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Two notes.  First, this will not include days that have no activity.  That is not the case for your sample data.

Second, this can be made more efficient.  However, performance does not seem to be an issue in your question.

Comment: And i'm the author of one of those answers ;) My previous comment was to your solution as it's an alternative to mine.